# SQL server connection not working

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, hibernate, ninject

I'm trying to create a blog with ASP.NET MVC.
I'm following this [guide](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/12/how_to_create_a_simple_blog_part1#blog)

At the middle of the guide (page 7) we test the app, but we have to change the connection string.

Since I don't have a database set up, I was hopping the connection will create it automatically, but it is not.

```
<add name="BlogDbConnString" connectionString="Data Source=WATCHTOWER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Blog;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I also have my user set with no password:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="XXXXX" password=""/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

When I try to run the app, I get an error in the code where the Ninject is supposed to create the DB:

```
public class RepositoryModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISessionFactory>()
          .ToMethod(e => Fluently.Configure()
          .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("AngelAlferezBlogDbConnString")))
          .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>())
          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Post>())
              .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false))  //<===THIS LINE!
          .BuildConfiguration()
          .BuildSessionFactory())
          .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<ISession>()
          .ToMethod((ctx) => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
          .InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

And a Hibernate exception saying:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Anyone can guess what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message actually says it all... Hibernate is attempting to create the database, but is unable to establish a connection to SQL Server to do so.

This is a pretty common type of error (often related to configuration of network protocols or security).

Refer to this article for a good checklist to diagnose and resolve this type of error

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Summary of steps from the article:

- SQL Server should be up and running.
- Enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration
- Open Port in Windows Firewall
- Enable Remote Connection
- Enable SQL Server Browser Service
- Create exception of sqlbrowser.exe in Firewall
- Recreate Alias

Comment: So is it enough with the sql server that comes with Visual Studio to make this work?

Comment: Your connection string says SQLEXPRESS, which is separate install.